# System shutdown directly from Xmonad - SLiM display manager

Tags: x11, xmonad, nixos

I just installed Nixos and Xmonad on top of X11 (in VirtualBox).

I can't find a command to trigger the shutdown from within the GUI. When I quit Xmonad I'm facing the graphical login, without any button.

This is what I did so far:

```
ALT + SHIFT + Q to quit Xmonad
CTRL + ALT + F1 to open a console
login as root
$ halt
```

Then I power off the VM when it's ready. I think you agree that it is kind of weird way to shut down a system :-)

EDIT: just found that **the default DM for Nixos is [SLiM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLiM)** which has been abandoned and I don't know how to configure it. I'm going to install a different, lightweight DM and try to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLiM is a bit user-unfriendly.  You are supposed to put the action as the login and then root's password as the password.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Shutdown.2C_reboot.2C_suspend.2C_exit.2C_launch_terminal_from_SLiM

There have been discussions about using something else by default, but most people will want to base the default choice on their default desktop environment, and we haven't reached a firm conclusion to switch.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :-) finally I switched to LightDM and the shutdown button is there out of the box.

Comment: I think your answer is the correct answer, even if I preferred switching to LightDM. I'm gonna accept it, thanks!